# Barkod scanner system

Tags: mobile, camera, qr-code, photo, face-recognition

I need a barcode reader system, but I need to not recognize the image when the barcode is photo taken. how can I do that. So ı need a barkod system that can not access with photo. Is there any technology to do that. I do not want to allow the user to take a picture of the bar code and read it from another device.

Comment: Can you explain in some other way? It sounds like you want a "thing" that can be seen (by a camera) but cannot be photographed? Which is physically impossible

Comment: in fact, basically, I'm trying to prove that someone is somewhere. but the mind did not come from the barcode. but people can take a picture of the barcode and read it in another place. I cant use location info because there is some fake location programs in mobile platform.

Comment: Imagine that You are in my house right now and I'm trying to prove it. How can I do this through the phone. There is an application and this application is accessible only when the user is in that location. But the user has to be inside, not outside my home

Comment: A bluetooth beacon may be the answer, they have been used for positioning in different applications. RFID tag scanned with NFC may also work for you. This question may be too broad for this site.

Comment: Allow barcode reading from live video but not from an image?

Comment: Yes  I thought but I can take a picture with my phone, and other person device readinf from life video on my phone